# calling a function from an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need more clarification for this problem.I have an object and it has two functions as like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
obj =
{
  f1 : function () 
  {
       var k = this. f2(param1 , param2 , param3);// I don't know whether it is correct
  },
  f2 : function (par1 , par2 , par3)
  {
      return param1 + param2 + param3;
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I call function f2 from f1? Can I declare f1 in f2? If yes, how is it? Which is the best method?

Comment: What you see in console after running the code?

Comment: you need to use a class constructor if you want to be able to use `this` in objects.

Comment: Did you try to run it in console?

Comment: BTW, `param1` is not the same as `par1`.

Comment: no i didnt. i asked this question for understanding the object and funtions relationships in this case. I am not getting it.

Comment: @Barmar - _"you need...a class constructor...to be able to use `this` in objects."_ - [No you don't.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pzm9a/)

Comment: @programmer_rkt - `this.f2();` will work within `f1()` if you called `f1()` with `obj.f1()`. But can you explain your use of `param1`, `param2`, and `param3` - they're not declared or assigned values anywhere in the code shown, and I can't tell whether they're supposed to be part of what you're asking about or just some kind of misleading simplification, or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it by the code you have given,but be care of the **scope**.
Please consider the output of following two part of code.

```
obj =
{
  f1 : function () {
       var k = this. f2(1 , 2 , 3);
  },
  f2 : function (par1 , par2 , par3){
      console.log(this);
      return par1 + par2 + par3;
  }
}
obj.f1();
```

and

```
obj =
{
  f1 : function () {
       var k = this. f2(1 , 2 , 3);
  },
  f2 : function (par1 , par2 , par3){
      console.log(this);
      return par1 + par2 + par3;
  }
}
function MyClass () {
    return this;
}
MyClass.prototype = obj;
var tmp = new MyClass();
tmp.f1();
```

You also can declare f1 in f2,but if you want to use f1 at the other place,you must write f1 agian.

Answer (score 1):

Not to replace the above answers, but to provide an alternative: when I write definitions of objects that have methods I prefer to use function constructor so that I can hide "private" closure variables and have some resemblance to OOP.

```
var myClass = function() {

    /******** PRIVATE **********/

    var _s = "foo";          // Private member
    var _f = function() {};  // Private method

    /******** PUBLIC **********/

    this.s  = "bar";          // Public member
    this.f1 = function() {    // Public method
        console.log(_s + " " + this.s);  // Concat private and public
    }
    this.f2 = function() {
        this.f1();
    }
}

var myObject = new myClass();
myObject.f2(); // prints "foo bar"
```

Comment: Nice example of private vs public +1. I seen examples of them but didn't understand how they were but I see having var in a function hides them like they do in normal functions.

Answer (score 0):

To share `this`, the functions would be better to be added to obj.prototype.

```
obj = {};
obj.prototype = {
    f1: function(){
    },
    f2: function(params){
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the benifit of doing so?

Comment: _"To share `this`, the functions would be better to be added to obj.prototype"_ - What? Why? Then you'd have to say `obj.prototype.f1()` to call the function. Using `this` the way the OP shows [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/Pzm9a/).

Comment: right, @lex-podgorny gives the best OO code, prototype could be used together with it and jquery $.extend :) I used to use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may give you a better idea. I have tested it it runs fine.

```
obj =
{
  f1 : function () 
  {
  console.log("in F1");
  obj.f2();
       },
  f2 : function ()
  {
      console.log("in F2");
  }
};

console.log(obj.f1());
```

Here is the fiddle to it => http://jsfiddle.net/CJ7Uz/

Answer (score 0):

Going off of Barmar's suggestion, here's what the code would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj = {
  f1: function ()  {
   var k = this.f2(param1 , param2 , param3);
  },
  f2: function (par1 , par2 , par3) {
    return par1 + par2 + par3;
  }
};
</script>
```

Also, bad idea to stick a space after `this.` in your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

calling f2 like this:

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
obj =
{
  f1 : function ()
  {
       var k = this.f2(1 , 2 , 3);// it is correct :)
       alert(k);
  },
  f2 : function (par1 , par2 , par3)
  {
      return par1 + par2 + par3;
  }
}

obj.f1();
</script>
</pre>
```

and check the link below to find the answer of your second question
http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Answer (score -1):

your problem is resolved:

```
      <a href="#" onclick="obj.f1()">Click</a>

       obj =
      {
        f1 : function () 
        {
            alert('f1');
            var param1=param2=param3=0;
             var k = this.f2(param1 , param2 , param3);

        },
        f2 : function (param1 , param2 , param3)
        {
            alert('f2')
            return param1 + param2 + param3;
        }
      }
```

For demo visit this link [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ApKvS/1/)

Comment: -1 for `var param1=param2=param3=0` and the inline event handler.

Comment: Its just a demo brother, not actual implementation.

Comment: it's fundamentally broken code because it creates `param2` and `param3` as global variables and not local.